# Binding an event after a page reload and creating new html element using Knockout.js, HTML and JS only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I am new to knockout libraries and we are working on an iPad web app. The situation is when a user check a checkbox in a HTML page, we need to add a new div in the page with some text boxes in it and remove it when he uncheck those.

Point to be noted: the new div is binded to data that needs to be default loaded in the text box or selects.

Its an iPad web app. It uses Knockout, jQuery, JS and HTML with MVVM.

The question is, can Knockout bind html elements after the page load, as custom handler works/register themselves only during init and can a dynamic div be created using js and html, if yes then how to put it between two static divs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind elements after page load using ko.applyBindings(viewModel, ElementSelector), like so:

```
ko.applyBindings(myModel, $("#myDiv"));
```

However, this isn't something you generally want to do.  It's much easier to use the If binding in Knockout, which will dynamically add or remove child elements from the page.

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind='checked: showChild' />
<div id="container" data-bind="if: showChild">
   <!-- stuff here will only be generated if the checkbox is selected -->
</div>
```

If you had multiple different elements to show based on a value of something, say a select list, you could use the template feature instead:

```
//viewmodel properties
self.Options = ko.observableArray(["Name", "Age", "Height"])
self.TemplateToUse = ko.observable() 


//html
<select data-bind="options: Options, value: TemplateToUse">
</select>

<div data-bind='template: { name: TemplateToUse }'>
   <!-- template whose name is selected value -->
</div>

//templates
<script type="text/html" id="Age">
   <span>Age</span>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="Name">
   <span>Name</span>
</script>

<script type="text/html" id="Height">
   <span>Height</span>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @SarahBourt, I am looking forward to implement it, never knew of template in knockout. I am marking it as an answer.

Comment: Cheers.  If you haven't already, head over to the documentation section of Knockout.js at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html

Knockout has great documentation :)

Comment: That I know. Thank you @SarahBourt I will continue with that.